# Custom VSCode Taskbar Labels on Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My current workflow has me opening upwards of 4 or 5 different VSCode work spaces.  It is nearly impossible to *quickly* keep straight which work space is which. The only indication given is in the title bar of the individual window, which means I'm often clicking through the windows to find the correct one.  It doesn't appear to be possible to rearrange the order of the VSCode task bar items within themselves (only in their current ordering with other apps).

Is there a way to rearrange the workspace name and the current file name to make the workspace first and the filename second?

Or is there a way to assign custom icons per workspace?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the setting `window.title` you can configure which parts are shown and there order.

Use the Setting GUI to see the possible fields.

```
${dirty}${rootName}${separator}${activeEditorShort}${separator}${appName}
```